# Trying to append objects to a list using MOUSEBUTTONDOWN

Tags: python, pygame

Im making a version of boids and im trying to append the boids to a list by using pygames MOUSEBUTTONDOWN fucntion. It works great to some degree. I want it to add one instance of the object, but it adds alot when im left clicking.

```
from precode import *
from config import *
import pygame as pg
from boids import Boid
from obstacle import Obstacle

def boids():
screen_res = (SCREEN_W,SCREEN_H)
pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode(screen_res)
clock = pg.time.Clock()
boids = []
obstacles = []
while True:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT or event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
                exit()
    pg.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), (0, 0, screen.get_width(), screen.get_height()))
    time_passed = clock.tick(60) # limit to 60FPS
    time_passed_seconds = time_passed / 1000.0   # convert to seconds


    if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == LEFT:
        x, y = pg.mouse.get_pos()
        obstacles.append(Obstacle(screen, Vector2D(x,y)))
    for obstacle in obstacles:
        obstacle.draw()

    if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == RIGHT:
        x, y = pg.mouse.get_pos()
        boids.append(Boid(screen, Vector2D(x,y), Vector2D(10,5)))
    for boid in boids:
        boid.move()
        boid.draw()

    pg.display.update()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    boids()
```

The class for both the boids and the obstacles are simple classes, and i can add them if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:` clause should be in the event loop. Check out if this version works as expected:

```
def boids():
    screen_res = (SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H)
    pg.init()
    screen = pg.display.set_mode(screen_res)
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    boids = []
    obstacles = []

    while True:
        time_passed = clock.tick(60) # limit to 60FPS
        time_passed_seconds = time_passed / 1000.0   # convert to seconds

        # Handle the events.
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT or event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
                    return
            elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == LEFT:
                    x, y = pg.mouse.get_pos()
                    obstacles.append(Obstacle(screen, Vector2D(x,y)))
                elif event.button == RIGHT:
                    x, y = pg.mouse.get_pos()
                    boids.append(Boid(screen, Vector2D(x,y), Vector2D(10,5)))

        # Insert game logic here.

        # Draw everything.
        pg.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), (0, 0, screen.get_width(), screen.get_height()))

        for obstacle in obstacles:
            obstacle.draw()

        for boid in boids:
            boid.move()
            boid.draw()

        pg.display.update()
```